# LDAP change password policy

Tags: php, ldap

I just updated the Password change policy in OUD with:

> password-change-requires-current-password = true;

in http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19623-01/820-6169/the-default-password-policy.html
it said:

> Indicates whether users are required to provide their current password when setting a new password. If this is set to true, then users are required to provide their current password when changing their existing password. This may be done using the password modify extended operation, or using a standard LDAP modify operation by deleting the existing password value and adding the new password value in the same modify operation.

I just updated the Password change policy in OUD with:

password-change-requires-current-password = true;

in http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19623-01/820-6169/the-default-password-policy.html it said:

```
Indicates whether users are required to provide their current password when setting a new password. If this is set to true, then users are required to provide their current password when changing their existing password. This may be done using the password modify extended operation, or using a standard LDAP modify operation by deleting the existing password value and adding the new password value in the same modify operation.
```

and now when I use `ldap_modify` to change an entry password it responds:

> resultCode: unwillingToPerform (53)
>
> LDAPMessage: modifyResponse(2) - unwillingToPerform: (The password policy requires that user password changes include the current password in the request)

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: did your request include the current password?